# Find what user edited what post in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Right now I have a simple blog website setup with devise which allows users to edit posts. I also have activeadmin installed on the backend. What I want is when a user signs in and they edit a post I want that users email to be tied to that post. Then I could go into active admin and setup the column to view the user later. Trouble im having is that im not sure how to automatically tag a users email to a specific post when they edit it, also my user and post model are on different tables in the database.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Couldn't you store the last user to update in the Post table?

Answer (score 0):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association

Just set up a join table for a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association on each model. This is a standard active record association which should be well-documented; see the link above for a start.

Then in your `update` method for the `PostsController` you can add a line like:

```
@post.users << current_user
```

(obviously the specific code will vary depending on the names of your variables & associations -- i'd probably rename the association to "editors" or something like that)

I don't know anything about active admin, so I can't tell you how to make these associations viewable there. But it shouldn't be too hard once the association is set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches I use to create user_stamps.

1. paper_trail gem that records all modifications in Version table.
   Works great with Active Admin.
2. Adding updated_by_id and created_by_id columns to all tables (paper_trail needed)

   ```
   # In each Model. 
   belongs_to :updated_by, :class_name => "AdminUser", :foreign_key => "updated_by_id"
   belongs_to :created_by, :class_name => "AdminUser", :foreign_key => "created_by_id"

   after_create { |i| i.update_column(:created_by_id, PaperTrail.whodunnit) }
   after_save { |i| i.update_column(:updated_by_id, PaperTrail.whodunnit) }
   ```

   These columns will be redundant but a great compliment to Version table and is faster and better for many reports and scopes.